# Database operations and calling API in single transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have 2 systems, one Identity Management System that handles authentication and another is an application (say UserApp) (website) that user access. When a user registers, the user account is created in Identity Management System and UserApp database. The data should be in sync between these 2 systems. So the current code does the following when user registers

1. the data is inserted into database (using Entity Framework)
2. Account is created in IAM using an API call

Scenarios:

1. If the database insert is failed then API is not called
2. If database insert is successful, API fails then we delete the record. **Question is what needs to be done if the delete fails, then the data is not in sync.**

What is the best way to handle? The application is developed in C# with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of database transactions. You could create a database connection and open it.. The first line should be `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.  This means any subsequent `SQL INSERTS/UPDATES` you execute wont be commited until you run the statement `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.. If you want to roll back the transaction you would call `ROLLBACK TRANACTION`.

So you could:

```
Step 01: BEGIN TRANSACTION
Step 02: Perform INSERT Statement.
```

If the SQL statement succeeds, you know the databse is up and accessible and this step has succeeded. It just that the row has not been commited to the database yet.

```
Step 03: On success of the INSERT statement, then Call the API
Step 04: If API SUCCEEDS then COMMT TRANSACTION.
Step 05: If API FAILS or there is an exception, then ROLLBACK TRANACTION
```

That way:

- If the SQL statement fails in any way (DB down, T-SQL error, etc), you exit early
- If the API call fails in any way, you exit early
- You only commit the SQL statement when the INSERT and the API succeeds

**If the COMMIT Fails**

Now there might be a slim chance the COMMIT fails due to power loss or network outage at that second, etc..  In that case you you would need to call the API to remove/deactivate the user you just created.

Comment: The only issue is I cannot delete from the IAM system as I don't have delete API, I think I don't have choice.